# Do Try Catch.. A whole block of code in Swift 2

Tags: swift, try-catch

Coming from Android, wrapping a block of code in a try..catch statement is straightforward.

```
try{
   //A whole lot of code
} catch (Exception e) {
   //Exception is a parameter
}
```

I wanted to do the same thing in Swift, but it doesn't seem to be quite this easy.
If I understand correctly, you need place a try in front of something that you think will go wrong.

Is there anything similar to the Android - functionality I described in the Swift toolbox?

Comment: How u managed that?

Answer (score 0):

Error handling in Swift 2 takes two things into consideration:

- Whether the method can throw an error (marked with `throws` keyword in its declaration).
- Whether the method that can throw is called from throwing scope (e.g. another methods that can throw) or not.

For non-throwing methods it's simple: you do not need to put any `try` or `do/catch`.

Methods that throw must always be prefixed by `try`, regardless of scope.  So, that's a part of the answer to your question.

In case if scope is throwing, you do not have to use `do/catch` (but you can).  In this case all errors thrown in current scope that are not handled by it will be passed upstream to the parent throwing scope.

If the scope is non-throwing, then you must handle all errors that can possibly be thrown by the methods that are called from said scope.  Therefore, you must use `do/catch`.

Depending on your particular case, you might have to put `do/catch` around as well.  If your current scope is non-throwing you will have to.

---

There are 3 types of `do/catch`.

**I. Catch all**

```
do {
    methodThadDoesNotThrow()
    try methodThatThrows()
}
catch {
    // This will catch all errors that can be possibly thrown.
    // You get implicit local-scope variable `error` that holds thrown error.
}
```

**II. Catch concrete error type**

Errors that can be thrown must implement `ErrorType` protocol.  This is the only pre-requisite.  They do not really have to be `NSError` or its descendants (this type is just a legacy from `Objective-C`).  Therefore, if you know the concrete error type that you expect you can do something like:

```
do {
    methodThadDoesNotThrow()
    try methodThatThrows()
}
catch let error as CustomErrorType {
    // This will catch all `CustomErrorType` errors. 
    // You get explicit local-scope variable `error` of `CustomErrorType` type.
}
```

**III. Catch concrete error instance**

Typically error types are declared as `enum`s.  For example:

```
enum CustomErrorType {
    case SomethingStrange(String)
    case SomethingMildlyHorrible
    case Apocalypse
}
```

If you want to catch some specific case of `CustomErrorType`, you can do:

```
do {
    methodThadDoesNotThrow()
    try methodThatThrows()
}
catch CustomErrorType.SomethingStrange(let message) {
    // This will catch only `CustomErrorType.SomethingStrange` errors. 
    // You get explicit local-scope variable `message` that 
    // will come from the value associated with the error enum-case.
}
```

---

There is, of course, the case of:

**IV. Combine all together**

```
do {
    methodThadDoesNotThrow()
    try methodThatThrows()
}
catch CustomErrorType.SomethingStrange(let message) {
    // This will catch `CustomErrorType.SomethingStrange` error. 
}
catch let error as CustomErrorType {
    // This will catch the rest of `CustomErrorType` errors. 
}
catch {
    // Finally, this will catch all the rest of the errors
    // (anything that is not `CustomErrorType` in this case).
}
```